# Does too many startup program damage Windows PC? And ways to slow down startup

Tags: window

I have many (~10 programs) startup programs to help me at my work, usually take me ~15 minutes wait time to actually start working.

I saw that my CPU usage & disk read write are pretty much >80% all the way during that ~15 mins start up time, and I was wondering **whether that these long startup time, with high resource utilization, will do large amount of damage to my Windows 10 PC?**

If so, if there any ways to cap the resources of my PC during startup, so maybe it will not damage my PC as much?

Thanks!

FYI, these are the typical software I run on startup: Outlook, Skype, multiple code editor (e.g. Atom, Eclipse and such), Ubuntu on VirtualBox and so on.

Comment: If it takes 15 minutes for your machine to startup, you have way to many programs configured, to automatically start when you log into your profile.  It should take a minure...tops

Comment: Without knowing what hardware your using like cpu speed, number of cores, memory size and etc we can't answer your question.  The startup time may cause some extra wear and tear on the hard drive, but it will not damage anything.  I suggest making sure you have at least 8gb if not 12gb of RAM.  Then buy a SSD or M.2 SSD depending on what your motherboard is capable of.  Most of the time its a hardware bottleneck.  Maybe chkdsk /r c: in case you have bad sectors on your hard drive, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running programs does not damage your PC in any way.  Running programs is exactly what it is designed to do!

However, if it takes that long to start your PC, it sounds like you have a low amount of memory and a mechanical hard drive.  During the boot process, even when the desktop shows up, Windows is starting services and running background applications.  Couple that with a large amount of programs you placed in the startup folder, the computer is constantly swapping memory and the hard drive is to slow with its responses.  Hence the 15 minute time to wait.

The obvious solution would be to not run all the programs at startup.  However, you can always purchase more memory and a SSD, which is always a great speed increase for most computers.